# Add Custom CCS to Specific Template Pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I wish to centre the  entry-title on certain pages in my Wordpress template using a body_class_filter. This will be based on the page template that is used.

e.g. Any page that uses page template pageshow.php should have custom CSS to centre the title.

I have read a few tutorials and comprehend what needs to be done. But my solution attempt isn't working. Here's what I tried...

I put the below at the bottom of my functions.php file...

```
if (is_page_template('pageshow.php'))
{ // Returns true when 'pageshow.php' is being used.
function my_class_names($classes)
{ // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
$classes[] = 'pageshowclass';
return $classes; // return the $classes array
}

// Now add pageshowclass class to the filter

add_filter('body_class', 'my_class_names');
}
  else
{ // Returns false when 'about.php' is not being used.
}
```

And the below in my stylesheet...

```
/* Custom Page Styling by ID */
.pageshowclass h1.entry-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

But the class is not applied, nor is the css. [Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-body-class-101-tips-and-tricks-for-theme-designers/) is some useful doco.

Comment: You could just add the class to your container in the actual page template

Comment: Yes I think that would work. Honestly I hadn't thought of it:) However I'd like to use this method because I'm teaching myself about template modification. I can use this technique for more than just page templates (e.g. categories) in the future.

Comment: Ok, well the code doesnt contain any obvious errors, does your theme support body_class?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme supports body_class. It should have the following in the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

If it does, check that your if condition is returning true, eg:

```
if (is_page_template('pageshow.php')){
    echo 'ITS WORKING';
}
```

Comment: Not sure where to check for `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` but I tried your second suggestion and it returned as working.

Comment: @square_eyes I image the opening body tag will be in the header.php file

Comment: Right, thats pretty odd do you have a live link?

Comment: Ok i'll take a look tomorrow and try and help further if no one else has spotted the problem by then

Comment: Hi @user574632 any luck?